# How to add firewall manager new ATP rule using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, web-application-firewall

I'm trying to add AWS Fraud Control account takeover prevention rule using CloudFormation, but I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for its configuration.
The WAFv2 API support the argument ManagedRuleGroupConfigs however, the Firewall Manager API does not talk about it anywhere.
Do you have any idea how to do it ? and what is the correct attribute.

This is what I tried so far :

```
{
        'ruleGroupType': 'ManagedRuleGroup',
        'overrideAction': COUNT
        'managedRuleGroupIdentifier': {
          'version': None,
          'vendorName': 'AWS'
          'managedRuleGroupName': 'TestATP',
          'managedRuleGroupConfigs': ['config here']
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an answer to this. The Account Takeover Prevention feature is not currently supported in Firewall manager. So there is no solution for this yet.